# Select Text on click Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I want to fix the following issue in Firefox

When i try to select the text inside the textbox using double click on mouse its not selecting the text the cursor goes to the start of the text.Any ideas how to fix this?but this works fine in googlechrome

i tried the following from this http://www.iwebux.com/demos/ajax/ i this link when you try to edit the price column you cant select the value.Thank you.

my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('td.edit').click(function () {
         $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
         $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');

         $(this).addClass('ajax');
         $(this).html('<input id="editbox"  size="' + $(this).text().length + '" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');

         $('#editbox ').focus();
     });

     $('td.edit').keydown(function (event) {
         arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
         if (event.which == 13) {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "supplierprice/config.php",
                 data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rowid=" + arr[2] + "&field=" + arr[1],
                 success: function (data) {
                     $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                     $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                 }
             });
         }
     });

     $('#editbox').live('blur', function () {
         $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
         $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code

```
$('td.edit').click(function(e){
            var $target = $(e.target);
            if($target.is('#editbox')){
                return;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.select()` function. This is used to select the text in the editable input elements.

In your case, try adding the line

```
$('#editbox').select();
```

below the line

```
$('#editbox ').focus();
```

Hope this hepls.

Comment: That will cause that you cant click inside the text, after click the text will be always selected.

Comment: @HarryFink Ahh! Yes, this one has that problem. Your solution will be a better one.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [select()](http://api.jquery.com/select/) instead of focus().

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your script a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/dKn4W/

The problem is that the click event bubbles up from the #editbox input, so the $('#editbox ').focus(); is executed on every click, that prevent text selection.

Modify your code something like this

```
        $('td.edit').click(function(e){
            var $target = $(e.target);
            if($target.is('#editbox')){
                return;
            }
            ///// rest of code
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the click events from propagating from `#editbox` to your `td.edit`. Try adding this:

```
$("td.edit").on("click", "#editbox", function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```